Confusion in complex numbers
Consider a quadratic equation az²+bz+c=0 where a,b,c are complex numbers. How can I comment on the nature of roots like:
Condition for both roots purely imaginary.

Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about how to ask a good question.

Welcome to MSE. Please, use MathJax to type the math in your questions. Consider that many users in this forum won't even read your question if it's not properly formatted, let alone help you.

Hint. Use Vieta's formulas.

@Gonçalo I disagree.  It is true that if both roots are imaginary that $~b~$ will be imaginary and $~c~$ will be real.  However, the converse is false, with counter-example $~z_1 = r + is, ~z_2 = -r + is.$

@user2661923, you are right. Vieta's formulas provide a necessary, but not sufficient condition.
